# Typeclasses and type inference in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-inference, typeclass

I'm trying to figure out how does type inference works together with type classes and so far struggle to grasp it fully.

Let's define the following simple `HList`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

infixr 6 :::

data HList xs where
  HNil :: HList '[]
  (:::) :: a -> HList as -> HList (a ': as)
```

Now I'm going to define type class that allows to "uncurry" any function into the function of a single argument of type `HList`:

```
class FnToProduct fn ls out | fn ls -> out where
  fromFunction :: fn -> HList ls -> out

instance (FnToProduct' (IsArity1 fn) fn ls out) => FnToProduct fn ls out where
  fromFunction = fromFunction' @(IsArity1 fn)

class FnToProduct' (arity1 :: Bool) fn ls out | fn ls -> out where
  fromFunction' :: fn -> HList ls -> out

instance FnToProduct' True (input -> output) '[input] output where
  fromFunction' fn (a ::: tail) = fn a

instance (FnToProduct fnOutput tail out') => FnToProduct' False (input -> fnOutput) (input ': tail) out' where
  fromFunction' fn (input ::: tail) = fromFunction (fn input) tail

type family IsArity1 fn where
  IsArity1 (a -> b -> c) = False
  IsArity1 (a -> b) = True
```

Now I'm going to break the compilation:

```
test = fromFunction (\a b -> a) (True ::: False ::: HNil)

• Ambiguous type variables ‘p0’, ‘p1’,
                               ‘out0’ arising from a use of ‘fromFunction’
      prevents the constraint ‘(FnToProduct'
                                  'False (p1 -> p0 -> p1) '[Bool, Bool] out0)’ from being solved.
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
      Relevant bindings include test :: out0 (bound at src/HList.hs:98:1)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘p0’, ‘p1’,
                                                          ‘out0’ should be.
      These potential instance exist:
        one instance involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression:
        fromFunction (\ a b -> a) (True ::: False ::: HNil)
      In an equation for ‘test’:
          test = fromFunction (\ a b -> a) (True ::: False ::: HNil)
   |
98 | test = fromFunction (\a b -> a) (True ::: False ::: HNil)
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But if I specify types of function explicitly:

```
test = fromFunction (\(a :: Bool (b :: Bool) -> a) (True ::: False ::: HNil)
```

It works just nice. How could I enforce type inference here so the compiler would pick up the types of HList to figure out types in function? I also tried to use `infixl/r` operators without any luck so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typeclasses are "matchy". In your example, GHC says it is trying to solve the constraint

```
FnToProduct' 'False (p1 -> p0 -> p1) '[Bool, Bool] out0
```

Where unification variables `p1` and `p0` coming from the implicit expansion of the first argument:

```
(\(a :: _p1) (b :: _p0) -> a)
```

and unification variable `out0` coming from the type of `fromFunction`. Essentially, GHC doesn't know what the argument types should be, nor what the `fromFunction` call should eventually return, so it creates three variables to represent them and tries to figure out what they should be.

No `instance` matches this constraint. The

```
instance _ => FnToProduct' False (input -> fnOutput) (input ': tail) out'
```

would require `p1` and `Bool` to be the same, but they aren't. They *could* be, as you demonstrate with your type-annotated example, but GHC believes that they don't *have* to be. You could imagine adding

```
instance _ => FnToProduct' False (Int -> fnOutput) (Bool ': tail) out'
```

and now you don't know whether `a :: Int` or `a :: Bool`, because both instances "fit". But, with the open world assumption, you have to assume new instances like this can be added whenever.

One fix is to use `~` constraints:

```
instance (i ~ i', o ~ o') => FnToProduct' True (i -> o) '[i'] o'
instance (i ~ i', FnToProduct r t o) => FnToProduct' False (i -> r) (i' ': t) o
```

The second instance now matches, because the two `i` variables are different. It actually *guides* type inference now, because the `i ~ i'` requirement, in this case, translates to a `p1 ~ Bool` requirement, which is used to instantiate `p1`. Similarly for `p0`, by the first instance.

Or, add another functional dependency. This doesn't always work, but it seems to do the job here

```
class FnToProduct fn ls out | fn ls -> out, fn out -> ls
class FnToProduct' (arity1 :: Bool) fn ls out | fn ls -> out, fn out -> ls
```

Which tells GHC that `fs` (and therefore its argument types, here `p1` and `p0`) can be figure out from `ls` (here `[Bool, Bool]`).

That aside, I think your function could be simplified to this:

```
class AppHList ts o f | ts f -> o, ts o -> f where
   appHList :: f -> HList ts -> o
instance AppHList '[] o o where
   appHList x HNil = x
instance AppHList ts o f => AppHList (t : ts) o (t -> f) where
   appHList f (x ::: xs) = appHList (f x) xs
```

Artificially requiring the `HList` to supply all arguments is not particularly useful, and it can really blow up in polymorphic contexts, because you often can't tell what "supplying all the arguments" is supposed to mean. E.g. const can have any number of arguments, from 2 up. So, `appHList const (id ::: 'a' ::: HNil) 6` works (where `const` has 3 arguments), but `fromFunction` fails in that context.

You can still impose the "returns a not-function" property externally to the more useful function, if you really want it.

```
type family IsFun f :: Bool where
  IsFun (_ -> _) = True
  IsFun _ = False
fullAppHList :: (IsFun o ~ False, AppHList ts o f) => f -> HList ts -> o
fullAppHList = appHList
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks!

Also, isn't it enough to have fundep `ts f -> o, ts o -> f` and get rid of equality constraint? At least it looks like it works without it

Comment: @SergeyKolbasov Oh, wow, I didn't think that would work. AFAICT, the `~` trick generally works in more places than fundeps, but fundeps, when they do work, tend to be better. Edited.

Comment: With a type family approach, it's possible to leave out the class. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option:

```
class (f ~ AbstractList ts o) => AppHList ts o f where
  appHList :: f -> HList ts -> o

type family AbstractList xs o where
  AbstractList '[] o = o
  AbstractList (x ': xs) o =
    x -> AbstractList xs o

instance f ~ o => AppHList '[] o f where
  appHList x HNil = x

instance (AppHList ts o f', f ~ (t -> f'))  => AppHList (t ': ts) o f where
  appHList f (x ::: xs) = appHList (f x) xs
```

Although there's only one equality constraint, this expresses dependencies in several directions. How's that? The key is that the type family can reduce as soon as the structure of the list is known; nothing is needed from the second argument and none of the list elements are needed either.

This seems to have the same inference power as HTNW's simplified version, but it has two advantages:

1. It's possible to get equality evidence if you need it.
2. It plays better with the `PartialTypeSignatures` extension. GHC seems to trip over the fundep version in that context for some reason. See [this ticket](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/17024) I just filed.

---

But wait! There's more! This formulation suggests that even having a class is optional! The class-based approach is likely to be the most efficient when everything specializes and inlines completely, but this version looks a lot simpler:

```
appHList' :: f ~ AbstractList ts o => f -> HList ts -> o
appHList' x HNil = x
appHList' f (x ::: xs) = appHList' (f x) xs
```